# How to read large file with unicode in Python 3

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x

Hello i have a large file that contain unicode characters, and when i try to open it in Python 3 this is the mistake i have.

> File "addRNC.py", line 47, in 
>       add_rnc()
>
> File "addRNC.py", line 13, in **init**
>       for value in rawDoc.readline():
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/codecs.py", line 300, in decode
>       (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 158: invalid continuation byte

And i try everything and didn't work, here is the code:

```
rawDoc = io.open("/root/potential/rnc_lst.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8')
    result = []
    for value in rawDoc.readline():

        if len(value.split('|')[9]) > 0 and len(value.split('|')[10]) > 0: 
            if value.split('|')[9] == 'ACTIVO' and value.split('|')[10] == 'NORMAL':
                address = ''
                for piece in value.split('|')[4:7]:
                    address += piece
                if value.split('|')[8] != '':
                    rawdate = value.split('|')[8].split('/')
                    _date = rawdate[2]+"-"+rawdate[1]+"-"+rawdate[0]
                else:
                    _date = 'NULL'

                id = db.prepare("SELECT id FROM potentials_reg WHERE(rnc = '%s')"%(value.split('|')[0]))()

                if len(id) == 0:
                    if _date == 'NULL':
                        db.prepare("INSERT INTO potentials_reg (rnc, _name, _owner, work_type, address, telephone, constitution, active)"+ 
                                "VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', NULL, '%s')"%(value.split('|')[0], value.split('|')[1], 
                                                                        value.split('|')[2],value.split('|')[3],address, 
                                                                        value.split('|')[7], 'true'))()
                    else:
                        db.prepare("INSERT INTO potentials_reg (rnc, _name, _owner, work_type, address, telephone, constitution, active)"+ 
                                "VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"%(value.split('|')[0], value.split('|')[1], 
                                                                        value.split('|')[2],value.split('|')[3],address, 
                                                                        value.split('|')[7],_date, 'true'))()
                else:
                    pass

    db.close()
```

Comment: What makes you think that the file is a Unicode file that’s encoded in UTF-8? Byte 0xD3 is a U+201D ʀɪɢʜᴛ ᴅᴏᴜʙʟᴇ Qᴜᴏᴛᴀᴛɪᴏɴ ᴍᴀʀᴋ in the MacRoman encoding, for example. Does the file validate as UTF-8?

Answer (score 5):

Your file actually contains invalid UTF-8.

When you say "contains unicode characters", you should be aware that Unicode doesn't specify how the characters are represented. So **even if the file represents Unicode data**, it could be in UTF-8, UTF-16 (UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE, each with or without a BOM), the deprecated UCS-2, or perhaps even one of the more esoteric forms...

Double check that the file is valid; I'd bet that you indeed have a byte 0xD3 (11010011), which must in UTF-8 be the leading byte of a two-byte character, in a follower position (in other words, 0xD3 immediately follows a byte whose binary representation begins with 11 [is greater than 0xC0]).

The most likely reason for this is that your file contains *non-ASCII* characters, but isn't in UTF-8.

Comment: I think is a Unicode character because on the 158 position there is a  'Ó'.

Comment: @hidura: Unicode and UTF-8 are **not the same thing**. Yes your file contains Unicode characters. That does *not* mean it is encoded in UTF-8. HTTP://regebro.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/unconfusing-unicode-what-is-unicode/ There is no character at all at position 158, there is a NUMBER. That number is 201. In UTF-8, that's an Ó, correct. In MacRoman, it's a quotation mark. Does the Ó make sense? What is position 157 and 159?

Comment: @hidura Not all non-English characters are Unicode. Many legacy documents use what are called *codepages* ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page ).

Comment: @Borealid: Which contains characters that are all part of Unicode, and hence are Unicode characters. :-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro Not exactly true; Unicode consolidated multiple previously-distinct glyphs into single characters in some cases, and the reverse in some cases. See the notes below the table on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437 ; the characters in a code page are tied to an intended visual representation, not a semantic meaning!

Comment: @Can you give an example of Unicode merging distinct glyphs? None of the comments you refer to contradict my statement above.

Comment: @LennartRegebro If you have a document in CP437 which uses the byte 0xE1, that might be a beta or it might be a sharp s. No lossless conversion to UTF-8 is possible. As for merging characters, the florin sign (U+0192) is a good example.

Comment: @Borealid: No automatic lossless conversion, you are right. But both the beta and the sharp S exists in Unicode. Which is why I asked for examples of Unicode *merging* distinct glyphs, because then you would have an argument. :-) This is in fact a case of *CP437* merging distinct glyphs.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Again, the florin sign.

Comment: OK, the florin-sign seems to be a mistake from the Unicode designers.  Does it exist in any code page? But yes, it can then be argued that if you have a character set with a florin sign, that is not a Unicode character. But that's not the case here.

Comment: Further reading on the issue shows that the mistake was indeed by adding "Florin sign" as alternative name to the letter "LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH HOOK". There is a proposal to add a separate code point for the Florin sign, but standard bodies move slowly. :-)