# UnicodeDecodeError when using pymssql with freetds

Tags: python, unicode, freetds, pymssql

I want to get a field in SQL server 2008 from python 2.6. Here is my freeTDS .conf file:

```
[ARGSERVER03]
    host = 192.168.1.3
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.0
```

Here is the code:

```
conn = pymssql.connect(host='192.168.1.3', user='****', password='****', database='TrafficMonitor', as_dict=True, charset='UTF-8')
i = 0
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM dbo.tblTrafficCounterData')
while i < 10:
    car = cur.fetchone_asdict()
    if car is None:
        break
    c = car['Class']
    print c
    i = i + 1
```

But it gives:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

The Unicode field is in Persian. The trace back is for line `car = cur.fetchone_asdict()`

**[Edit]**

I have checked for database collation in database properties from sql server management studio and it is:

```
Arabic_CI_AS
```

But when I use that in charset it gives:

```
LookupError: unknown encoding: Arabic_CI_AS
```

Comment: This error seems to be very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090915/how-to-read-large-file-with-unicode-in-python-3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you extremely sure that SQL Server is using UTF-8 (indicated by your `charset='UTF-8'`)?  Typically most SQL Server instances I have run into use a Microsoft encoding (not UTF-8), such as cp1252 (in the U.S.).

A few things that may help you discover the correct encoding:

`SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('dbname', 'Collation') SQLCollation`

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508.aspx
- [Python Encodings Table](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

Comment: Arabic_CI_AS is the SQL Server name for the collation, it only provides a hint as to the Python encoding to use.  Try using `cp1256` as the charset (`cp1256` is for Windows Arabic, as shown at http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)